# How can I find out in which referred js-script the called function is

Tags: javascript, function

when I call a js-function I want to know in which referred script the called function is located.

example:

index.html contains 
scriptpath1
scriptpath2
script....n

....
fooFunction

So how can I found out in a fast way where the foo() is located without exploring the whole dirs?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would open up dev tools
2. In Chrome navigate to the sources tab.
3. From here right click on the server/page name and select **Search in all files**
4. Enter the search term in the console box at the bottom of the window
5. ...
6. Profit?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of browser dev tools and figure it out